# Enabling duplucate names in flask app.route

Tags: python, flask

I am new to web and am writing a website with flask to display algebra and geometry problems. My html templates are organized as follows:

```
...
├── problems
│   │
│   ├── algebra
│   │   │
│   │   ├── algebra_all.html
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── geometry
│   │   │
│   │   ├── geometry_all.html
│   │   └── ...
...
```

I want to define a view function for both categories algebra and geometry as follows:

```py
@app.route('/problems/<category>/<category>_all')
def category_all(category):
    return render_template(f'problems/{category}/{category}_all.html')
```

but I receive the error

```py
  File "<werkzeug routing>", line 1
SyntaxError: duplicate argument 'category' in function definition.
```

I tried looking up the documentation but could not find a solution to my problem. Then I started to rummage in the source code but this is too tiresome.

How could I solve my problem? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can change it to `@app.route('/problems/<category>/all')` to make your life easier.

Comment: Very good idea @David! Thanks.

Comment: Anyway I would like to know if there is a way to use a variable twice in app.route rule. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK that is not possible. You can try having two different variables and verify their value is the same in your code maybe? But I can't think of a scenario when that would be necessary.

Comment: Yeah, I see, thanks!

Comment: can you make an other variable in the function and just copy the category? `cat = category` and then do `f'problems/{category}/{cat}_all.html`

Comment: @BendikKnapstad yeah, David proposed this idea too